# Using Let's Encrypt on Amazon AMI (Centos) - can't even install package, any ideas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, encryption, amazon-ami, certbot

Following instructions here : https://ivopetkov.com/b/let-s-encrypt-on-ec2/

I tried this : `git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --debug`

and got the error: u*nknown option `debug'*

I removed the --debug and got this error : *Too many arguments.*

So, I'm pretty much stuck in the water.  I tried this a few months ago with a different tutorial and got further along but certbot itself returned a warning that using an Amazon AMI (which I am) is problematic.

I get this error when running `./certbot-auto` for instance :

> FATAL: Amazon Linux support is very experimental at present...
>   if you would like to work on improving it, please ensure you have backups
>   and then run this script again with the --debug flag!

Has anyone had luck setting up a Let's Encrypt SSL with an Amazon AMI ?

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

This is one command, which clones the git repo into `/opt/letsencrypt`:

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
```

This is a second command, which runs the installer:

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --debug
```

The formatting on the page you linked makes those look like one single command.